# Revert Back Modified Record

Tags: extjs

I am using Editor Grid,I need to revert back modified records,Right now am using refresh() but it refreshes entire modified values,I need to revert back only specific records so any another function available to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `reject` method of specific record:

- [Ext.data.Model.reject](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-reject) (ExtJs 4)
- [Ext.data.Record.reject](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Record-method-reject) (ExtJs 3)